# Fabric, @parallel and dynamically changing hosts

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I have a script that launches EC2 instances and passes the new instances public DNS as a list to another class which attempts to deploy code and stuff on it.

My deployment process is using @parallel in order to parallel the entire process per host.
I've encountered a barrier I've not yet been able to overcome, by trying to set the env.hosts when my deployer class instantiates.

It seems that the @parallel decorator causes my tasks to be forked before the env.hosts is set, thus the tasks are not familiar with the new hosts.

```
class Deployer(object):

"""Deploys workers code on given list of workers"""

   def __init__(self, hosts):
        env.hosts = hosts
        global pool_size
        pool_size = len(hosts)

   @parallel(pool_size=pool_size)
   def update_workers(self):
       sudo("aptitude update")
       #skip grub update.
       sudo("DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::=\"--force-confdef\" -o Dpkg::Options::=\"--force-confold\" dist-upgrade")

   @parallel(pool_size=pool_size)
   def copy_conf_to_worker(self, local_path):
       result = put(local_path,'/tmp/',use_sudo=False)
```

When calling the class:

```
deployer = Deployer(hosts)
deployer.update_workers()
```

I'm getting prompted for hosts:

```
2014-08-20 14:15:30,896 INFO 41 Going to deploy the next hosts: ['some-host.compute-1.amazonaws.com']
No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:
```

Is this possible, or should I just consider another course of action?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a solution, so I used a workaround:
I moved the tasks into a fab file:

**fabfile.py**

```
from fabric.api import *
# Fabric related conf
env.disable_known_hosts = False
env.reject_unknown_hosts = False
env.use_ssh_config = True
env.connection_attempts = 3
env.coloreize_errors = True
env.forward_agent = True
pool_size=len(env.hosts)

@parallel(pool_size=pool_size)
def update_workers():
    sudo("aptitude update")
    #skip grub update.
    sudo("DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::=\"--force-confdef\" -o Dpkg::Options::=\"--force-confold\" dist-upgrade")

@parallel(pool_size=pool_size)
def copy_conf_to_worker(local_path):
    env.host_string = env.host
    result = put(local_path,'/tmp/',use_sudo=False)
```

And from within the code I called the fable.py:

```
def run_fabric_tasks(self, path_to_conf_file):
        cmd = 'fab update_workers copy_conf_to_worker:%s -H %s' % (path_to_conf_file, ",".join(self.hosts))
        result = local(cmd)
        deploy_workers(path_to_conf_file)
        return result
```

I know that this could be more elegant(arguments / command wise), but this is just a raw solution that worked for me.
If there's anything more elegant, I'd like to know.